# How to construct a regular expression pattern from string

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I am using regular expression in Node.JS

```
var Regex = require("regex");
var regex = new Regex(/(a|b)*abb/);
regex.test("abb");   // true 
regex.test("cabb");  // false
```

In this case, the pattern is

```
`/(a|b)*abb/`
```

`var regex = new Regex(/(a|b)*abb/);` is correct

`var regex = new Regex('(a|b)*abb');` is error

Now I have a string `'(a|b)*abb'`. How do I construct a regular expression pattern from this string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Both are incorrect.**

The correct way is to use the `RegExp` constructor.

```
var regex = new RegExp('(a|b)*abb');
```